# How to format the date picker (DD.MM.YY) in an userform

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, date-formatting, week-number

thank you reading my question once again. I am entering a date in a column range and I notice difference in format between the two dates entered using following method.
Method 1: I have a custom made userform to enter the date in the active cellas seen in [Date picker-custom date picker pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJGY.png)

Method 2: I use the Cntrl+: together to enter the date.

I although have the cell format same but I notice a difference in the two date which I investigated by using the LEN formula in excel.

LEN gives me for the date 05.08.2021 as 10 by method 1 and by method 2, the LEN is 5.
In the next step, I use this date to derive the calender week number and since there is difference in both the methods, I get error using the medthod 1 and it works fine with method 2.Most probably it is becuase the method 1 hold a svalue which is very long and since in my calender week vba I have this dim as integer i get the error.

Thank you and hope I recieve help here.

[Two same dates created by the above two methods explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE3iT.png)
in the second column where results are 5 and 10. It is derived by using excel formula LEN. My week number vba which extracts week number from these dates works only on the date which has result 5 i.e when the LENGTH of a string is 5. But when its 10 for example in this case I get run time error 6 as show in the picture [Run-time error 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg1Yn.png)

Comment: Well yes, its vba tool in excel

Comment: @Vicky How are you putting the selected date from the datepicker into the cell?

Comment: @norie Hi, I have attached a picture of the userform.

Comment: @Vicky It's actually the code that's being used to transfer the value from the datepicker to the sheet I was interested in. Can you post that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When putting dates into cells you shouldn't use `Format` as that converts them to text.

Instead you should use CDate or DateValue to get a 'real' date value that you can format as you want, and use in calculations/comparisons.

So, in the posted code try replacing this,

```vb
Range(cCell).Value = Format(sDate, DatePickerX_DateFormat)
```

with this.

```vb
Range(cCell).Value = CDate(sDate)

Range(cCell).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy" ' added on 05.08.2021
```

Note, you might not need the 2nd line as Excel might automatically format the date as required, based on locale settings of course.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. It really solved my problem. I am working on this project and maybe, I would be posting so more questions. But yes, this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

*Actually the code is pretty messed up. I hope this is the code that u wish to check.*

```
Sub setDate()
Dim tempUFX As Object
'Dim tempUFX As Object

Dim ufr As Object
For Each ufr In UserForms
If ufr.Name = FormName_SetDate Then
      Set tempUFX = ufr
  Exit For
End If
Next ufr

If Not tempUFX Is Nothing Then
   'Set tempUFX = UserForms(FormName_SetDate)
   tempUFX.Controls(ctrlName_SetDate).Value = sDate
  
   tempUFX.Controls(ctrlName_SetDate).SetFocus
End If
Unload PopDatePickerX
Range(cCell).Value = Format(sDate, DatePickerX_DateFormat)

'Range(cCell).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy" ' added on 05.08.2021

    Unload PopDatePickerX
End Sub
```

Comment: For future questions, please edit your question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

another error occured - VBA Run Time Error 1004: Method “Range” of object’ _ Global’ failed:

following is the code:

```
Sub setDate()
Dim tempUFX As Object


Dim ufr As Object
For Each ufr In UserForms
If ufr.Name = FormName_SetDate Then
      Set tempUFX = ufr
  Exit For
End If
Next ufr

If Not tempUFX Is Nothing Then

   tempUFX.Controls(ctrlName_SetDate).Value = sDate
  
   tempUFX.Controls(ctrlName_SetDate).SetFocus
End If
Unload PopDatePickerX
Range(cCell).Value = CDate(sDate)


    Unload PopDatePickerX
End Sub
```

The solution previously mentioned worked but that was the case when I have a date calender for a defined range (column O and Column R). The same datepicker is also used on userform and now when executing this userform, after the selection of date this error occured.

The debugger highlights on the following line:-

```
  Range(cCell).Value = CDate(sDate)
```